# Как использовать декораторы в классе, которые используют инициализацию класса Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, декоратор

Есть код телеграм бота с методами с декораторами.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    ...

@bot.message_handler()
def echo_message(message):
    ...

bot.parse_mode = 'html'
bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Я хочу вынести всё в класс, чтобы вся инициализация и методы были сгруппированы, но не могу понять, что делать с декораторами `@bot.message_handler`, так как они используют переменную бота.

Вот, что я примерно пытаюсь сделать:

```
class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
        self.bot.parse_mode = 'html'

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  # <- что-то нужно сделать с ботом
    def start(self, message):
        ...

    @bot.message_handler()  # <- что-то нужно сделать с ботом
    def echo_message(message):
        ...

    def run():
        self.bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

На Гитхабе нашел [репозиторий с проектом](https://github.com/AleXLaeR/Telegram-Bot-Product-Store), в котором решается эта проблема. Вкратце, создается класс-handler, который обрабатывает сообщения. Например, обработка команды `/start`:

```
class CommandHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def handle(self):
        @self.bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
        def handle(msg) -> None:
            if msg.text == '/start':
                self.bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Hello! Waiting for other commands')
```

```
class MainHandler:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self._bot = bot
        self._com_handler = CommandHandler(self._bot)
        # self._text_handler = MiscTextHandler(self._bot)
        # self._inline_query_handler = InlineQueryHandler(self._bot)

    def handle(self):
        self._com_handler.handle()
        # self._text_handler.handle()
        # self._inline_query_handler.handle()
```

```
class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bot = telebot.TeleBot(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
        self._handler = MainHandler(self._bot)

    def _start(self) -> None:
        self._handler.handle()

    def run(self) -> None:
        self._start()
        self._bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

```
bot = TelegramBot()
bot.run()
```